# MySQL connection not working on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, connection

Any clue as to why this would not work in a Windows environment?

It works under Linux

```
function dbLink(){

$host = 'localhost';
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$base = '';
mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($base) or die(mysql_error());

}
dbLink();
```

Thanks

Comment: Got any error messages? the code looks fine as is, so until you give us more info, we can't help you.

Comment: Are the blank login details correct for your windows machine as well? or maybe you just removed them while posting here, which is fine.

Comment: No user name. Maybe your Linux distribution is using the current logged on user. That's a configuration issue.

Comment: Does your windows machine have MySQL extension enabled?

Comment: try with the port number.. 3306 default port for mysql

Comment: details were omitted on purpose - my connection to the server hangs if I enable this function - maybe I will just make a raw connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try 127.0.0.1 instead. Your localhost might be set to something different.

Make sure PHP for windows has php-mysql installed and enabled.

Comment: I actually changed the host name too for obscurity - you know what? it must be a problem with the server itself because this was working last night

Comment: Try putting the new hostname in your hosts file with it's IP address. If that works it might be a DNS issue.